# The right way to provide derived defaults for Gradle task properties

Tags: gradle

I am writing a Gradle task to generate a certain configuration file needed for application deployment. I would like to let users customise the name and the location of the generated file.

A rough sketch of the task class would be:

```
class ConfigurationFileTask extends DefaultTask {

    String configFileName = 'config.xml'

    File configFilePath = new File(project.buildDir, configFileName) 

}
```

The idea is to let users override either the filename, or the whole file location, as they wish.

I realise that the code above wouldn't actually work, because `project` is not defined when the initialiser for `configFile` runs; my problem is working out the right way to do this.

Now, i would like the task to be a good citizen in the wider build, which means that other tasks should be able to refer to its properties. For example, i would like users to be able to write:

```
task createConfigFile(type: ConfigurationFileTask) {
    configFileName = 'app-config.xml'
}

jar {
    from(createConfigFile.configFilePath)
}
jar.dependsOn createConfigFile
```

And have that add the generated config file to the jar. Note that in this case, the user is setting the `configFileName`, but referring to the `configFilePath`. That means that the path must be computed some time after the name is set.

So, how can i provide a property which can be set by the user, but has a default based on another property, and where the property is usable by other tasks?

Answer (score 1):

make it a method then, this definitely works

```
task overrideBoth(type: ConfigurationFileTask) {
    _configFileName = 'app-configb.xml'
    _dir = '../'
}   

task overrideFileName(type: ConfigurationFileTask) {
    _configFileName = 'app-confign.xml'
}

task overridePath(type: ConfigurationFileTask) {
    _dir = '../../'
}

task defaultBehavior(type: ConfigurationFileTask) {
}

class ConfigurationFileTask extends DefaultTask {
    def _configFileName = 'config.xml'
    def _dir = project.buildDir
    def getFile() {
        return new File(_dir,_configFileName)
    }   
}   

task otherTask(type: DefaultTask) {
    println("defaultValues ${defaultBehavior.getFile().canonicalPath}")
    println("overrideFileName ${overrideFileName.getFile().canonicalPath}")
    println("overridePath ${overridePath.getFile().canonicalPath}")
    println("overrideBoth ${overrideBoth.getFile().canonicalPath}")


}
```

configFileName gets overriden

Comment: It does work. But it doesn't have anything to do with my question. Your code shows the creation of a property that is simply initialised with a default, which can then be changed. It doesn't do the kind of derived default that i want to do.

Comment: question was: The right way to provide defaults for Gradle task properties?

I don't think I follow what you are asking then, on my code, configFileName has a default value and you can override it after as you want.

Comment: If you read my question, not just the title, it explains what i need.

Comment: That's getting closer. That lets the user set `_configFileName` and then read either that or `fileName` (which i think should really be called `filePath`). But it doesn't let the user set `fileName` directly. As i say in my question, i want the user to be able to set either of the properties.

Comment: Tom, what's been lacking this example is coding, the basics were there since the beginning. Good thing about gradle is that you can code your build manager. Anyways it DOES all you need